# Go to implementation or Go to definition not working VS CODE for Jsx

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsx

F12 and go to definition, [go to implementation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-implementation) does not work

- Expected: Context menu should show an entry `go to implementation`
- Actual: Context menu lacks this option

#### Screen of context menu

[image: Visual Studio Code - context menu go to definition missing]

The same code is working for everbody in our team.

Is it a vs code issue or something else?